# How to close one instance with another class in java

Tags: java, oop

I have this problem since I'm beginning in OOP programming I want to close one Class from other Class who have been called by this Class I want to close.

EX:

Class Principal call Class Menu and inside menu i close Principal

```
//Im inside of Principal

Menu mnu = new Menu();

//Now im inside of Menu

public void closePrincipal(){

principal.close();
}
```

Comment: Without more context it's difficult to know what you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the reference to the principal class to the menu;

// in your principal

```
Menu mnu = new Menu(this);
```

You have to define that constructor in the Menu class:

```
class Menu{
    private Principal principal;

    public Menu(Principal principal){
      this.principal = principal;
    }
...
}
```

So when you want to use it in your menu, just do it.

```
principal.close();
```

Comment: Why should Menu in the first place be responsible for closing the resources on the caller? This breaks encapsulation and increases coupling.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Im inside the code of class Principal", you may want to think as "I have make a variable based on Class principal, and I am executing some code for that variable".

You have turn a definition ( "class" ) into an specific object.

Answer (score 0):

Create the menu and pass the principal

```
Menu mnu = new Menu(this);
```

In the menu:

```
private Principal principal;

public Menu(Principal principal) {
    this.principal = principal;
}

//You can close the menu's principal any time by calling this...
public void closePrincipal() {
    principal.close();
}
```

You can close the principal this way

```
mnu.closePrincipal()
```

Or close it at the Menu's constructor.